# Will be vs arrive vs show up

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between the following sentences:

> 1 I will be there at 6 pm.

> 2 I will arrive at 6 pm.

> 3 I will show up at 6 pm.

Does the second one make sense if, for example, I'm going to a party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I will be there at" says that the speaker will be present at that time, but perhaps s/he will arrive before the stated time. Numbers 2 and 3 mean the same thing, but "show up" is significantly more casual than "arrive" and might be better suited when discussing a party.

Comment: I would understand "I will be there at..." to indicate intended time of arrival.

Comment: @KateBunting: It's just a matter of context. *I'm not going out until 7 o'clock tonight, so **I will be there at 6** if you want to pop round for a quick chat*.